# Search crawls never ends

Tags: 2013, enterprise-search, crawl, content-source

We have 3 content sources, 2 are for SharePoint sites and one for SharePoint profiles. if we start a full crawl on one content source at a time, crawl ends without issues. But when full crawl is started on more than one content source, those crawls never end (even for the incremental). We removed and created the search service application many times, but the problem persists. And when we try to start the search crawls one by one, it never stops, it seems like something is broken and could not be repaired.

Here's a screenshot of our crawl load report :
[image]

Search Topology:
[image]

One of the errors that I found is the following :
[image]

In fact, the crawl component is gathering items, and we checked this in the local temp gatherer location, files are being downloaded, but it seems like it Content Processing Component is not processing items, due a communication error or something else, as described by the crawl load report.

Comment: Did you checked ULS?

Comment: Yes, nothing interesting. I'll be checking the Crawl Health Reports and share them with you.

Comment: What's your topology and how much content are you crawling?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I've added the search topology above.